# Сохранение и загрузка картинки во внутренней памяти Android устройства

Tags: android, java

Есть Bitmap image и String dir. Надо:

- Сохранить image во внутренней памяти, запомнить адрес в dir в png
- Загрузить из png по адресу dir в image

Сохранение я нашел на хэшкоде:

```
OutputStream stream = context.openFileOutput("test.png", MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE);
bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 70, stream);// пишем битмап на PNG с качеством 70%
stream.close();
```

А вот с загрузкой пока не понятно...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`BitmapFactory.decodeFile()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.html#decodeFile(java.lang.String)) или [`BitmapFactory.decodeStream()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.html#decodeStream(java.io.InputStream)).

Comment: Спасибо, похоже это поможет. У меня только еще один не большой вопрос. Программа ругается на строку с открытием файла, мол, такого не существует. Как корректно проверить на существование и создать в случае отсутствия, или нужен другой MODE?

Comment: Проверить существование файла вы можете, например, следующим образом:

    context.getFileStreamPath(fileName).exists();

----

И да, лучше использовать `MODE_PRIVATE`, пока вы точно не уверены, что вам нужен именно `MORE_WORLD_READABLE` или `MODE_WORLD_WRITABLE`. А начиная с API 17, эти два режима и вовсе объявлены как deprecated.

Comment: И все-таки странно, во всех примерах среда нормально реагирует на строку

stream = context.openFileOutput("test.png", context.MODE_PRIVATE);

Без всяких дополнительных реверансов, а у меня ругается, мол FileNotFoundExeption. Спасибо большое за ответы! Пока правда на рейтинги влиять не могу..

Comment: Так всё верно. Если вы посмотрите в документацию на метод [openFileOutput][1], то увидите, что он объявлен, как `throws FileNotFoundException`. Взглянув на иерархию этого исключения, становится очевидно, что это `checked exception`, а стало быть, вы обязаны его обработать.

  [1]: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#openFileOutput(java.lang.String, int)